# Find the most recent file saved under same name but in different directories using .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

The directories are the 3 below

```
    filename = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    filenameprint = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    pathload = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

And the file is saved as printout.pdf in all the 3 directories.

I'm thinking of using the LastWriteTime function but I do not know how to stack for the latest.

Comment: ??? You can get FileInfo of your file per folder. Compare .LastWriteTime to get file you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
    var files = new List<string>() {filename, filenameprint, pathload};
    var newestFile = files.Select(file => new FileInfo(file)).OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).First();
```

Edit: naturally you will have to combine the filename with the paths, otherwise this does not make much sense.